# Difference between AJAX request and a regular browser request

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Is there a difference between an AJAX request and a direct browser request (in terms of how a web page is called and loaded)?

In other words, I mean: is a direct server-side request handled in any way differently than a client-side request (initiated by the browser)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

An AJAX request is *identical* to a "normal" browser request as far as the server is concerned other than potentially slightly different HTTP headers.  e.g. chrome sends:

```
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

I'm not sure if that header is standardized or not, or if it's different in every browser or even included *at all* in every browser.

---

edit: I take that back, that header is sent by jQuery (and likely other JS libraries), not the browser as is evidenced by:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/');
xhr.send();
```

which sends:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie: ....
Host:stackoverflow.com
If-Modified-Since:Sat, 31 Dec 2011 01:57:24 GMT
Referer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685750/how-does-an-ajax-request-differ-from-a-normal-browser-request/8685758
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.12 Safari/535.11
```

which leads me to the conclusion that *by default* there is absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 43):

There may be some header differences, but the main behavior difference is on the client.

When the browser makes a regular request as in `window.location.href = "index.html"`, it clears the current window and loads the server response into the window.

With an ajax request, the current window/document is unaffected and javascript code can examine the results of the request and do what it wants to with those results (insert HTML dynamically into the page, parse JSON and use it the page logic, parse XML, etc...).

The server doesn't do anything different - it's just in how the client treats the response from the two requests.

Answer (score 3):

Some popular client-side libraries like [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/#jQuery-ajax) include the `X-Requested-With` header in their requests and set it to `XMLHttpRequest` to mark them as AJAX.

This seems to have been considered standard enough a few years ago (probably due to the huge popularity of jQuery and its presence in almost every website) that many server-side frameworks even have helpers that take care of checking for this header in the received request for you:

[**ASP.NET MVC 5:**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

```
HttpRequestBase.IsAjaxRequest()
```

[**Django:**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax)

```
HttpRequest.is_ajax()
```

[**Flask:**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.is_xhr)

```
flask.Request.is_xhr
```

However, it seems that with the end of jQuery's reign in the front end world and the standardization of the `fetch` API and the rise of other modern client-side libraries that don't add any header for this purpose by default, the pattern has fallen into obsolescence also in the backend; with ASP.NET MVC not including the helper in [newer versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282190/where-is-request-isajaxrequest-in-asp-net-core-mvc) and Flask marking it as deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Except that most Ajax clients send a `X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest` HTTP header

Answer (score 1):

I always check if "text/html" is the request's "best" Accept mimetype, because browsers always send that as the first.

Firefox example:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

Of course, this may still be a ajax request with text/html as the Accept mimetype, but I found this to be reliable when you know what client will consume your backend api.

Answer (score 1):

An AJAX request in Blink and Gecko-powered browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge etc) will send [this header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Dest) with AJAX requests:

```
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
```

That means that:

> The destination is the empty string. This is used for destinations that do not have their own value. For example fetch(), navigator.sendBeacon(), EventSource, XMLHttpRequest, WebSocket, etc.

Safari does not send this header at the time of writing (and IE never has and never will, but it's only a few months before IE should be completely irrelevant).

Answer (score -2):

your user-agent, aka browser, sends an XHR header which you can catch from php like this:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']
```

Comment: As stated in other answers, it's not the browser who puts that header in the request, but some front-end libraries.