# Where is Request.IsAjaxRequest() in Asp.Net Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

To learn more about the new exciting Asp.Net-5 framework, I'm trying to build a web application using the newly released Visual Studio 2015 CTP-6.

Most things looks really promising, but I can't seem to find Request.IsAjaxRequest() - a functionality I've been using quite frequently on older MVC projects.

Is there a better way to do this - that made them remove this method - or is it "hidden" somewhere else?

Thanks for any advice on where to find it or what to do instead!

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's still there. It's an extension method in `System.Web.Mvc`, class `AjaxRequestExtensions`. That's for MVC5, I don't know about MVC6...

Comment: That's what the OP is asking about: MVC6. Of course it's still there in MVC5.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Ok, yes, I'm testing MVC6. I might be wrong of course, but it seems to be missing from the "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3" package - or any of the other standard mvc-6 packages that comes with a new mvc-6 project.

Comment: Not sure about this but try just: `IsAjaxRequest()`, without the `Request.` prefix.

Comment: For a temporary solution on this, I decided to copy and modify the method from System.Web.Mvc.AjaxRequestExtensions. Hope it helps others, until this finds it way to the framework.


    public static class AjaxRequestExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequest request)
        {
            if (request == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
            }

            return request.Headers != null && request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
        }
    }

Comment: I think someone need to edit this question and change MVC5 to MVC6 in title.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I got a little confused, because the title mentioned MVC 5.

Search for [`Ajax` in the MVC6 github repo doesn't give any relevant results](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Ajax), but you can add the extension yourself. Decompilation from MVC5 project gives pretty straightforward piece of code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines whether the specified HTTP request is an AJAX request.
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <returns>
/// true if the specified HTTP request is an AJAX request; otherwise, false.
/// </returns>
/// <param name="request">The HTTP request.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="request"/> parameter is null (Nothing in Visual Basic).</exception>
public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequestBase request)
{
  if (request == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));
  if (request["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
    return true;
  if (request.Headers != null)
    return request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
  return false;
}
```

Since [MVC6 `Controller`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Controller.cs) seems to be using [Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpRequest](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/HttpRequest.cs), you'd have to check [`request.Headers` collection](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/IHeaderDictionary.cs) for appropriate header by introducing few adjustments to MVC5 version:

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines whether the specified HTTP request is an AJAX request.
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <returns>
/// true if the specified HTTP request is an AJAX request; otherwise, false.
/// </returns>
/// <param name="request">The HTTP request.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="request"/> parameter is null (Nothing in Visual Basic).</exception>
public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequest request)
{
  if (request == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));

  if (request.Headers != null)
    return request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
  return false;
}
```

or directly:

```
var isAjax = request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"
```

Comment: The source code from the version of MVC5 is here: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AjaxRequestExtensions.cs

Answer (score 41):

in asp.net core, You can use Context.Request.Headers.

```
bool isAjaxCall = Context.Request.Headers["x-requested-with"]=="XMLHttpRequest";
```

Comment: what is namespace for `Context` ?

Comment: @Aligned No, there is nothing in the fetch spec about adding an identifier in the request headers.  The X-Requested-With isn't in the XMLHttpRequest spec either ( hence the "X-" prefix), but all the vendors added it as a convention.  There is no indication any convention will done for fetch.

If your system needs to know then you need to manually add a header when creating your fetch request

Answer (score 11):

For those who are working on ASP.Net Core

```
HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
```

Example
 
**Controller.cs**

```
bool isAjax = HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";

if (isAjax)
   return Json(new { redirectTo = Url.Action("Index", "ControllerAction") });
else
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "ControllerAction");
```

Answer (score 4):

After using the solution provided above by Patryk Ćwiek above I noticed a potential issue (largely due to my incorrectly typing "XMLHttpRequest" as "XmlHttpRequest"), which resulted in an incorrect return value. To accommodate my mistake, I updated it slightly. Here's my updated version:

```
    public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));

        if (request.Headers != null)
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Headers["X-Requested-With"]) &&
                string.Equals(
                    request.Headers["X-Requested-With"], 
                    "XmlHttpRequest", 
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining the top 2 answers, this is what worked for me

**_ViewStart.cshtml (Entire Contents):**

```
@{
    bool isAjaxCall = Context.Request.Headers["x-requested-with"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
    
    Layout = isAjaxCall ? null : "_YourLayoutName";
}
```