# POST and GET in the same form created by BeginForm method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.beginform

How to create a form that has a search function (pull data from the database) AND a submit function (add data to the database) at the same time using the `BeginForm()` method? I am reviewing the overloads on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx) and I don't seem to find one.

Code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
    <table>
    @*Bunch of textboxes and dropdown lists*@
    </table>
    <div id=" buttonHolder">
        <input id="Search" type="button" value="Search" />
        <input id="Reset1" type="reset" value="Reset" />
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Add" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Are you submitting and searching at the same time?

Comment: @drew not the same time. when `Search` is hit, search, and when `Add` is hit, submit. I just want both methods in the same form

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework/7111222 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555265/asp-net-mvc-core-6-multiple-submit-buttons/36557172

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two approaches here:

1. handle `onsubmit` and fetch/save data with AJAX (you can do it even with `Html.BeginForm` but it's easier to go just with regular `<form ...`)

`@using (Html.BeginForm("DoIt", "DoItAction", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "submitWithAjax(event); return false;" }))`

2. create two separate forms with a different action/controller pair

Comment: Can I use `Ajax.BeginForm`?