# Can I redirect to a different action within a Form?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC, currently I have a Login page and I'm trying to add a new button: "Create User" to redirect the client to a different action.

These are my codes so far:

View:

```
<form class="login-form" action="/Login/Login" method="POST">
    <div class="login-form__content">
        <div class="login-form__header">Login to your account</div>
        <input class="login-form__input" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <input class="login-form__input" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <button class="login-form__button" type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.login-form,
.login-form * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.login-form {
    max-width: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.login-form__content {
    padding: 30px;
    background: #eeeeee;
}

.login-form__header {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
}

.login-form__input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #dddddd;
    background: #ffffff;
    outline: none;
    transition: border-color 0.5s;
}

    .login-form__input:focus {
        border-color: #0366d6;
    }

    .login-form__input::placeholder {
        color: #aaaaaa;
    }

.login-form__button {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #46a7e0;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

    .login-form__button:active {
        background: #46a7e0;
    }

.login-form__links {
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

How can I add a button within the form that would not direct the client to the action="/Login/Login" but instead to another action for example action="Login/Create" ? I'm concerned that if I add a button within the  it will still continue to redirect the client to "/Login/Login".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you handle multiple submit buttons in ASP.NET MVC Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework)

Comment: I would suggest https://stackoverflow.com/a/57633055/2208058 which is an answer linked from that for .NET Core

Comment: Good suggestions, just somewhat complex to implement for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the beginning. Just use a button with type button instead of submit like this

```
<form class="login-form" action="/Login/Login" method="POST">
    <div class="login-form__content">
        <div class="login-form__header">Login to your account</div>
        <input class="login-form__input" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <input class="login-form__input" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <button class="login-form__button" type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
<button id="createFormButton" class="create-form__button" type="button">Create User</button>
```

This button will not submit your form and you can easily redirect to action using `$('#createFormButton').click(function(){ some redirect here})`

also don't put direct action in this button as you may need it to use in some other triggers also later like for validations.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way

```
<a href=""/Login/Create">
    <button class="login-form__button">Create</button>
</a>
```