How can I paginate an ASP.NET Core MVC view to call a stored procedure from a controller action method each time the user changes pages
I have a SQL Server database and am using an ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC app and Entity Framework Core. I want to call a stored procedure that paginates its result set by page number and number of results per page in a controller action.
I thought the view could just call the controller action method over and over again with different page numbers, but when the view calls the next action the second time (I can call it once successfully), the model has a page number of 1 - even though I am displaying it on the page and it says 2.
I am actually calling an action method for Next, Back, First, and Last that decrements, increments or changes the current page number respectively and then calls the search controller action method with the model updated for a new current page. I'm not sure if this is best practice either.
The first time I call Next, the page number gets updated to 2 and the stored procedure is run again and retrieves the correct data. The second time I call Next, the current page is passed on the model as 1 even though it is displayed on the screen and shows 2.
Here is the applicable code. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SEARCH]      
     ...
     @PageNumber int = 1,
     @PageSize int = 20
 
    SELECT ...(columns)... 
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE
        ...
        OFFSET ((@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize) ROWS      
        FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
END

View:
<form id="frmSearch" method="post" asp-asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Search">

...
The button that calls the Search initially:
    <button id="submitSearch" type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Search</button>

The button that calls next:
    <input id="btnNext" type="submit" value="Next" asp-action="Next" />

The Hidden fields to pass the values:

    @Html.HiddenFor(h => Model.CurrentPageNumber)
    @Html.HiddenFor(h => Model.PageSize)
    @Html.HiddenFor(h => Model.TotalPageCount)
    @Html.HiddenFor(h => Model.TotalRecordCount)


The controller:
public async Task<IActionResult> Next(SearchViewModel svm)
{
    svm.CurrentPageNumber += 1;
    return await Search(svm);
}

Search (Post):
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search(SearchViewModel svm)
{
    try
    {
        // ...
        var parameters = new[]
            {
                new SqlParameter("@PageNumber", svm.CurrentPageNumber),
                new SqlParameter("@PageSize", pagesize)
            };
 
        List<CommunicationSearchResult> communications = await _recordingContext.CommunicationSearchResults.FromSqlRaw("EXEC USP_DETAILED_SEARCH_COMMUNICATIONS @PageNumber, @PageSize", parameters).ToListAsync();

        svm.Results = communications;

        if (communications.Count > 0)
        {
            svm.TotalRecordCount = communications[0].Total;
            svm.TotalPageCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((decimal)(svm.TotalRecordCount / pagesize)));
        }

        return View("Search", svm);
    }
    catch()
    { }
}


When it comes to ASP.Net, an important detail is that any appearance of passing objects back and forth between the server and the view is an illusion and not the same as a view model in something like MVVM /w WPF etc.  In order for a "model" to pass back anything other than its default state when passed back to a controller, you need an input element on the page that correlates to that value.
If you have a view model that has a CurrentPageNumber that you are adjusting server-side and/or client side then you may find the code starts working by adding a hidden input to the page for that value. For instance:
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CurrentPageNumber)

When you pass a model to a view, you are sending that instance of the class to the view engine on the web server. That view engine turns a .cshtml template and the model into a .html view, along with ASP.Net's JavaScript which manages things like form postback. When the user Posts a form or gets FormData to send to an Ajax call to the server, there is no "Model" instance on the client side. The JS merely attempts to parse all input values on the .html page to send those in the server POST. When your controller route gets called, ASP.Net will go through those inputs and construct a new ViewModel instance populating whatever values were passed. Any values not passed will be left as default.
Having a element content like a <p> or label with the @Model.CurrentPageNumber would display the updated Page #2 when you load the updated page, however without an <input> bound to @Model.CurrentPageNumber that updated value would not get passed with subsequent POSTs.
Alternative approaches to paging would be to track the current page number entirely client-side in JS and pass the current page # (and things like page size) with the POST payload rather than sending the view model with every call.  The current page number could also be tracked server side using Session State, though I don't really recommend that approach for storing transient state. (Easy to get out of sync and heavy use of session state for stuff can tie up server-side memory)
On a side note, when using EF you should very rarely need to resort to a Stored Procedure as this for the most part defeats the purpose of using EF. EF easily supports pagination through the Skip() and Take() methods, just be sure to include an OrderBy variant to ensure that the queries are consistently repeatable.

Thank you for your reply.  I do have hidden fields for the values on my page.  I have edited the post to include them.  The CurrentPageNumber is still not getting updated.  As for the Stored Procedure, I am joining tables from multiple databases (i.e. DBContexts).  I didn't think I could handle this with EF.  The tables are in a Data Warehouse and the result set can be millions of rows.  I figured a Stored Procedure was my only option.

Personally I haven't used form post submits for years except for very simple cases but I don't believe asp-action on the submit button is valid. For multiple submit actions you can use formaction /w Html5. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555265/asp-net-mvc-core-6-multiple-submit-buttons) Whenever I do pagination I use "button" type buttons /w JS handling GET calls to the server and render/replace the results container element contents. POST calls should not return a View(), but redirect to the base route /w a page number argument. I.e. .../Search?page=2 being a GET.

Thanks for the comments.  I did change the asp-action to formaction, but that didn't solve my problem and I ended up changing it back to asp-action.  I am still setting the CurrentPageNumber on the Server Side, but in all of the Javascript click events (Back, Next, First, and Last) I had to add this code:
var hdnCurrentPageNumber = document.getElementById("CurrentPageNumber");
var hdnTotalRecordCount = document.getElementById("TotalRecordCount");
var hdnTotalPageCount = document.getElementById("TotalPageCount");
var hdnPageSize = document.getElementById("PageSize");
hdnCurrentPageNumber.value = '@Model.CurrentPageNumber';
hdnTotalRecordCount.value = '@Model.TotalRecordCount';
hdnTotalPageCount.value = '@Model.TotalPageCount';
hdnPageSize.value = '@Model.PageSize';

I have the same code on my search javascript method, the only difference is that I am hardcoding the CurrentPageNumber to "1".
I don't understand why this works.  I would think this is what the binding of the hidden fields should be doing.  Can anyone enlighten me?

The submitting the Search, Previous, Next, First, and Last method works for me.  The View was not keeping the arrays that I was taking as Table Parameters for the Stored Procedure, so on the Search Action I saved the selected arrays into the Session.  In the Previous, Next, First, Last, and Go to Page Actions I get those arrays from Session and add them back to the ViewModel before calling the search method with the updated Page Number.  Everything seems to be working as I expected.

From my comprehension, you are using Html-helper and it retrieves data from ModelState first if not null. The page is not refreshed so when you submit you could check the modelstate is not updated. You could clear the modelstate to get this work.
