# Refresh PartialView in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to refresh my Partial View after submitting a form which will be processed in my controller. The problem is that whenever I try to refresh it form my controller, I get redirected to a blank page with content from the Partial View.

Partial View

```
@model Smarty.Viewmodels.BugViewModel

<div class="modal fade" id="bugModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Bug Reporting Tool</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form asp-controller="Smarty" asp-action="SendBugReport" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.message))
                {
                    if (!ViewBag.IsError)
                    {
                        <span class="border border-success text-success">@ViewBag.message</span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span class="border border-danger text-danger">@ViewBag.message</span>
                    }
                }
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                    <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>

                    <label asp-for="FormFile" class="control-label"></label><br />
                    <input asp-for="FormFile" type="file" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="FormFile" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Schliessen</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="BugReportBtn" class="btn btn-success">Bug Report senden</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendBugReport(BugViewModel viewModel)
   {
    //Process Form

    return PartialView("BugModal", viewModel);
   }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need the Partial View to appear on the page refresh? If not you can just return the `View` you want to navigate to instead (`View("SomeView", viewModel);`)

Comment: @Dortimer No, I want to refresh the Partial View with content like Error Messages, Success messages etc.

Comment: That's doing a full POST. You need to use AJAX as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202804/submitting-a-razor-form-using-jquery-ajax-in-mvc6-using-the-built-in-functionali

Comment: if you only want the partial view to update, you should consider just creating a full page/controller for it and placing it in an iframe. (Or process the form via javascript...)  Otherwise just return... the partial will be refreshed along with the page.

Comment: I deleted the answer I submitted. @SteveGreene is correct. I don't believe there is an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get redirected to a blank page with content from the Partial View.

That is expected because you use `return PartialView()` which will return the simple partial html to render it into the view.

> I want to refresh the Partial View with content like Error Messages, Success messages etc

You could not get `@ViewBag.message` from the `SendBugReport` action, it is passed from the action of main page.

As the comment has said that, first of all, you could use ajax to submit the form to `SendBugReport` action.Then the action return  `message` and `isError` json data to ajax success function. Finally, you render `message` on the view based on the value of `isError`:

1.Partial View (Views/Shared/BugModal.cshtml)

```
@model BugViewModel

<div class="modal fade" id="bugModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Bug Reporting Tool</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form id="myForm" asp-controller="Smarty" asp-action="SendBugReport" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div id="result"></div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                    <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>

                    <label asp-for="FormFile" class="control-label"></label><br />
                    <input asp-for="FormFile" id="FormFile" name="FormFile" type="file" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="FormFile" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Schliessen</button>
                    <button type="button" id="BugReportBtn" class="btn btn-success">Bug Report senden</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#BugReportBtn').on('click', function (event) {

        var url = "/Smarty/SendBugReport";

        var description = document.getElementById("Description").value;
        var fileInput = $('#FormFile')[0];
        var formFile = fileInput.files[0];

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("Description", description);
        formData.append("FormFile", formFile);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            processData:false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (!data.isError) {
                    $("#result").html("<span class='border border-success text-success'>" + data.message + "</span>");
                } else {
                    $("#result").html("<span class='border border-danger text-danger'>" + data.message + "</span>");
                }              
                $('#bugModal').modal('show');

            }

        });


    });
</script>
```

2.Action

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> SendBugReport(BugViewModel viewModel)
    {
        //Process Form

        string message;
        bool isError;

        //set data to message and isError
        return Json(new { message, isError });

    }
```