# Javascript File Download issue, returning strange string

Tags: javascript, http

I have the following HTTP Axios getcall that should result the browser to force a download but I get the a strange result instead.

AXIOS Call

```
    axios.get('http://localhost:63464/api/Consumer/ExcelDownload')
    .then(res => {
        return res.data;
    })
    .then(res =>
    {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err =>
    {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Which is returning the following result from the line in console.log(res);

[Result of console.log(res.data) image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFygA.png)

I was doing the following in the past to get this to work.
location.href = 'http://localhost:63464/api/Consumer/ExcelDownload';
which would return my File result.
however this route is now protected using a JWT which I have set in axios global headers, so this is no longer working for me.

Would someone be able to help me with this issue?
perhaps even being able to create some kind of URL from a blob that I can make the same call to.

Comment: are you trying to trigger the browser to dowload the file?

Comment: @DacreDenny - **Yes** I am. Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: I faced this problem recently - my solution was to verify the user's credentials via a cookie on server side. Is this possible for you?

Comment: Im not sure, I have never done it via a cookie before. 
I Authenticate the user using a JSON Web Token.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938718/how-to-download-files-using-axios

Comment: Thank you for your help @Dacre, I was able to Download but the file is Corrupted

Comment: @DacreDenny - Thank you for all your HELP!
I was able to figure out from the link you have sent me.
I also needed to make an adjustment to my JS HTTP Caller to get it to work.

Comment: For Anyone reading this... I was able to follow the Link @Dacrea Sent me and also needed to make an slight adjustment via my HTTP Caller. I am using AXIOS, and I needed to do the following to get it to work ...https://thewebtier.com/snippets/download-files-with-axios/

Comment: You're welcome glad I could help 