# Download file by NodeJS and SailsJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I need to make an APIto download a static file `test.js`.

When I test the API with Postman the result is just display the content of file, not downloading.

Is that ok?

```
async downloadTemplate(req , res) {
    let fs = require('fs');
    if(fs.existsSync('downloads/test.js'))
    {   
        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + 'test.js');

        let filestream = fs.createReadStream('downloads/test.js');
        //return res.download('downloads/test.js' , 'test.js')
        return filestream.pipe(res);
    } else {
        res.json({error : "File not Found"});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Postman should not be used for downloading files.

The client that will consume the API should decide what to do with the result.

If the client is going to be a browser - just test the api with a browser, not with postman.

In case the link to the server is in html - use the `download` attribute in the [href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes)

In case you are using Axios you can find the help you need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41940307/3107689)

Comment: how i can consume that in react.js 

i made that in react js 
and in downloadFile() i just call the api .. but no file downloaded @yeya

 <a href="#"  className="link" onClick={() => {
                downloadFile();
                
              }} download  >

Comment: You don't need onClick, just put the link on the href : `<a href="downloads/test.js" className="link" download>` .
Check this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: how can i do that >>>the response not "downloads/test.js"
i couldn't know the url ..

Comment: what should i do in 
 static jwtRequest(urlPath, options) {
        const headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "access_token": AuthModel.token()
        });

        return _request(urlPath, options, headers);
    }

Comment: that's the response 
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://crm.nozol.local:1339/contacts/contacts/downloadtemplate"
__proto__: Response


the file not downloaded .. what should i do?!