# File download with reactjs doesn't work correctly (using axios)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download, axios, youtube-dl

I'm implementing a youtube video downloader using [ytdl-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core) with Nodejs backend and Reactjs frontend. However, using ytdl-core library I'm able to send to youtube video file to frontend with this codeblock

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
    let { url, itag } = req.query;
    let id = ytdl.getURLVideoID(url);

    ytdl.getInfo(id, (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        }
        else{
            let audioandvideo = ytdl.filterFormats(info.formats, 'audioandvideo');       
            let video = audioandvideo.filter(obj => obj.itag === itag);

            video = video[0]

            res.header('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename="${info.title}.${video.container}"`);
            res.header('Content-Type', 'video/webm');

            ytdl(url, {
                format: video
            }).pipe(res); 
        }             
    })
});
```

However, the file downloads correctly if I redirect the webpage to the route like this

```
window.location.href = `http://localhost:5000/download?url=${this.state.url}&itag=${itag}`;
```

This works fine and the video downloads correctly. But as it's a redirection I can't do that in a hosted site. So, I need to use axios to do this.

I did some research and found out some solutions. I tried with [js-file-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-file-download) library following the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938718/how-to-download-files-using-axios). It downloads the file to the client directory but the file won't play. This is the codeblock I used for that

```
  downloadVideo(itag){

    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/download`, {
      params: { url: this.state.url, itag },
    })
    .then(response => {
      fileDownload(response.data, `video.mp4`);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

As it's not working I tried another approach mentioned in the previously mentioned StackOverflow answer as well. It also downloads the file but doesn't work as well.

How can I get this fixed? What may be the reason my axios request doesn't work correctly?

**EDIT** :

```
downloadVideo(itag){
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/download`, {
      params: { url: this.state.url, itag },
      responseType: Blob
    })
    .then(response => {
      fileDownload(response.data, `video.mp4`);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    // window.location.href = `http://localhost:5000/download?url=${this.state.url}&itag=${itag}`;
  }
```

This is the frontend code. If I use the commented code block (`window.location.href`) instead of `axios.get` the file gets downloaded and it works. But if I use `axios.get` a file gets downloaded but it seems to be a broken file as it's not playing.

Comment: Can you try setting `responseType` to `blob`? [Documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)

Comment: @HardikModha tried that. Still the same. The file gets downloaded but not playing

Comment: It is supposed to be "blob" (string). You have kept it `Blob`. Can you please confirm if it's the same code you tried? Can you post a link to codesandbox with [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?