# Download file functionality for react and python app

Tags: python, reactjs, python-2.7, file, download

I have one button in my react code and when I click it I should be able to download a file. I am using Python for backend(Not any framework). For react part I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938718/how-to-download-files-using-axios) link explains what should be done. On button click, I should do an API call and on its return, I can render this IFrame component. Also, one other answer recommends `responseType: 'blob'` in axios call. My question is what should the backend do if we want to send a file over.Let's assume it just creates a file and returns it. I am actually using one third-party product which has its own API interface but an example with `requests` library would do.

```
def function_called_From_endpoint():
    with open(path) as f:
        return {'data': f }
```

Is something like this right?

Comment: The code you posted will return a python dictionary object containing a python [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) Which probably Node cannot handle. Are you trying to return the contents of the file from the python function?

Comment: Yes I know returning file object won't work

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do? It seems to me you could just have the backend return a url to the file and have node get and download it.

Comment: @Alex I am trying to generate a file in backend and send it to UI on button click so that it can be be downloaded as attachment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I made it work this way:

```
def function_called_From_endpoint():
   with open(file_path) as f:
      data = f.read()

   return {"data": data }
```

and on the front-end:

```
  axios({
        url: url, //your url
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'blob', // important

  }).then((response) => {
         const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
         const link = document.createElement('a');
         link.href = url;
         link.setAttribute('download', 'file.txt'); //or any other extension
         document.body.appendChild(link);
         link.click();
  });
```

As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/53230807/5573241. It worked well.