# Download PDF with laravel-dompdf with vuejs front-end

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I created an API with Laravel. I use Vuejs for the front end.

I would like to generate a PDF based on the user and download it with view. Only, it does not work.

Here is my controller:

```
public function generate($id)
    {
        $data = CoverLetter::where([
            ['id', '=', $id],
            ['user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id]
        ])->first();

        $path = public_path() . '/pdf/' . $data->filename . '.pdf';

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.coverletter', $data);

        $pdf->save($path);

        return response()->download($path);
    }
```

And my function in vue :

```
async downloadCoverLetter(file) {
   axios.get('/cover-letter/generate/' + file.id)
}
```

And my button for download :

```
<button @click="downloadCoverLetter(file)"></button>
```

But it doesn't download at all. How to do ? Thank you !

Comment: Do you actually want to download the pdf or show it in your view?

Comment: You can check the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938718/how-to-download-files-using-axios

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try to download file using Axios using following code:

```
axios({
  url: '/cover-letter/generate/' + file.id,
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'blob', // important
}).then((response) => {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. responseType: 'blob', // important solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you need to check if your code is generating PDF properly at path you have provided. If it is then following functions will work for you

// Download
return response()->download($pathToFile);
return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);

// Render
return response()->file($pathToFile);
return response()->file($pathToFile, $headers);
```