# How to return PDF file in an Graphql mutation?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm using React and Graphql on the frontend and Django and Graphene on the backend.

I want to be able to download a pdf file of a report. I try to do it using **mutation** as follows:

```
const [createPdf, {loading: createPdfLoading, error: createPdfError}] = useMutation(CREATE_PDF)
const handleCreatePDF = async (reportId) => {
        const res = await createPdf({variables: {reportId: parseInt(reportId) }})
        debugger;
    };

export const CREATE_PDF = gql`
    mutation ($reportId: Int!) {
        createPdf (reportId: $reportId){
            reportId
        }
    }
`;
```

On the backend I have something like this:

```
class CreatePDFFromReport(graphene.Mutation):
    report_id = graphene.Int()

    class Arguments:
        report_id = graphene.Int(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, report_id):
        user = info.context.user

        if user.is_anonymous:
            raise GraphQLError("You are not logged in!")

        report = Report.objects.get(id=report_id)
        if not report:
            raise GraphQLError("Report not found!")

        if user != report.posted_by:
            raise GraphQLError("You are not permitted to do that!")

        html_string = render_to_string('report.html', {'report_id': 1})

        pdf_file = HTML(string=html_string)
        response = HttpResponse(pdf_file, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="rapport_{}"'.format(report_id)
        return response


        # return CreatePDFFromReport(report_id=report_id)
```

When I uncomment `return CreatePDFFromReport(report_id=report_id)` it works fine.

But I want to return pdf file.

Is there any possibility to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: @xadm And what is the best way to do that? Add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### It can't be done by mutation only.

You can't return file(binary)/headers(mime)/etc (needed to be handled as download request behaviour by browser) using json'ed communication. GraphQL request and response are in json format.

### Solution

Workflow:

- call a mutation (passing parameter in variables)
- resolver creates file content and saves it somewhere (file storage on server or s3)
- resolver returns a file `id` to be a part of download url or full `url` (string) to target file

`id` or `url` in this case should be a part of required mutation response

```
 mutation ($reportId: Int!) {
     createPdf (reportId: $reportId){
        reportDownloadId
    }
 }
```

- mutation result (and our `reportDownloadId`) is available in `data`

`data` (result/response) from mutation can be accessed in two ways:

... by `{ data }` :

```
const [addTodo, { data }] = useMutation(ADD_TODO);
```

... or by `onCompleted` handler:

```
addTodo({ 
  variables: { type: input.value },
  onCompleted = {(data) => {
    // some action with 'data'
    // f.e. setDownloadUrl(data.reportDownloadId)
    // from 'const [downloadUrl, setDownloadUrl] = useState(null)'
  }}
});
```

Both methods are described in [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/mutations/#update-data-with-usemutation)

Both methods will allow you to render (conditionally) a download button/link/component, f.e.

```
{downloadUrl && <DownloadReport url={downloadUrl}/>}

{downloadUrl && <a href={downloadUrl}>Report ready - download it</a>}

// render download, share, save in cloud, etc.
```

**Handler method can be used to automatically invoke downloading file request**, without rendering additional button. This **will look like one action while technically there are two following requests** (graphql mutation and download). This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41938718/6124657) describes how to handle downloads using js.

Answer (score 2):

You can encode your PDF to Base64 and send it as a string.
Then just decode it on the frontend.

Note that the Base64 uses 4 bytes to encode every 3 bytes (3MB file becomes 4MB string).

Comment: sure, but 33% more ... method suitable to embedding icons, svg, small files ... or small scale

Comment: Does decoding on frontend automatically download the file?