# how to download files using apis in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I've to just hit this api and file will be downloaded for the client. Somehow this doesn't work

```
let res=await axios.get(urlDownload,{params},{responseType: 'blob'})
```

or

```
let res=await axios.get(urlDownload,{params})
```

Edit:

- api doesn't get hit with this, however on running the generated url
  in browser, file gets dowloaded (with following message)

[image]

-able to veiw the response in the network tabs
[image]

Comment: "This doesn't work" is not informative or helpful. Try giving us more information e.g. error you're getting, what are you trying to acheive what kind of params object you're passing. how the server end is implemented. Everything that could help us understand where the problem is located.

Comment: @OrelEraki please check

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your own machine. You should be able to connect to it unless your firewall is blocking you. What's the exact URL you're trying to download?

Comment: @Slbox in networks tab i can see the url, on clicking it the file is getting dowloaded

Comment: @devb Did the server located on your personal computer ? And are you sure you paste the url in browser and navigating to it and it download the file + shows the error afterwards ?
Also please paste the full generated url

Comment: Yes the server in local , pasting the url in edits

Comment: @devb have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/53230807/303254 ?

Answer (score 0):

Either place a codesandbox where you have your full code or
check your set up against the code below:

```js
function download(values) {
    ...
    const method = 'GET';
    const url = 'http://my.api/download';
    ...
    axios
      .request({
        url,
        method,
        responseType: 'blob', //<< important
      })
      .then(({ data }) => {
// do something with the data
      });
  };
```

Not clear what you have in `params`