# How to get axios-cache-adapter to cache file downloads with responseType blob?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, axios, localforage

For some reason `axios-cache-adapter` is not caching `GET` requests for file downloads which I believe is due to setting `responseType: 'blob'` (as I don't have caching issues on other requests that don't require this field be set as such) which is required for axios to generate the src url(as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41940307/10261711)):

> src: URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data])),

My adapter setup is as follows:

```js
// set axios defaults
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

const configureAxios = async () => {

  await localforage.defineDriver(memoryDriver);

  const forageStore = localforage.createInstance({
    driver: [
      localforage.INDEXEDDB,
      localforage.LOCALSTORAGE,
      memoryDriver._driver
    ],
    name: 'my-cache'
  });

  return setup({

    // `axios-cache-adapter` options
    cache: {
      maxAge: 15 * 60 * 1000,
      exclude: {
        query: false
      },
      store: forageStore,
    }
  });
};

// call this function in JSX Component to download file
export const downloadFile = async (fileId) => {
  const api = await configureAxios();

  const response = await api.get(`api/download/${fileId}`, {
    responseType: 'blob',
  });

  return response.data; // returns file data
};
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: According to one of the package maintainers, [caching binaries is disabled](https://github.com/RasCarlito/axios-cache-adapter/issues/82#issuecomment-486659883) . Looks like there is a PR to enable this that is [still pending](https://github.com/RasCarlito/axios-cache-adapter/pull/94)

Comment: @D-Money I see, thanks for that, any idea how I might overcome my dilemma in the iterim?

Comment: In this case I think your only alternative to waiting for the update, would be to fork the `axios-cache-adapter` repo, make the change yourself, and install your version in your project instead of the original. 

This of course means you won't receive any updates to that package unless you manually update your forked version to get them. But as an interim solution it would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@D-Money](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8708201/d-money) pointed me in the right direction. So basically `axios-cache-adapter` v3 fixes the issue of not caching requests with `responseType` `blob` or `arraybuffers`, however it's currently only available in beta so you'll have to install that as follows in the interim:

> npm install axios-cache-adapter@beta

Then you'll have to make a slight adjustment by setting `readHeaders: false,` in the `axios-cache-adapter` options in `setup` and additionally move the axios default config directly into `setup`, which in my case results in the following net changes:

```js
const configureAxios = async () => {

  await localforage.defineDriver(memoryDriver);

  const forageStore = localforage.createInstance({
    driver: [
      localforage.INDEXEDDB,
      localforage.LOCALSTORAGE,
      memoryDriver._driver
    ],
    name: 'my-cache'
  });

  return setup({

    // Options passed to `axios.create()` method
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },

    // `axios-cache-adapter` options
    cache: {
      readHeaders: false,
      maxAge: 15 * 60 * 1000,
      exclude: {
        query: false
      },
      store: forageStore,
    }
  });
};

// call this function in JSX Component to download file
export const downloadFile = async (fileId) => {
  const api = await configureAxios();

  const response = await api.get(`api/download/${fileId}`, {
    responseType: 'blob',
  });

  return response.data; // returns file data
};
```