# Downloading files to client with django and GCP

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, download, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to **download a file from Django to client using GCP**. Currently, the request is made from axios, the file is fetched from GCP using url from the model. This file is then downloaded and returned as a HTTP response to the client. Inside the network tab, I can see a 200 OK response and the image is visible in the preview. However, the download is not being saved to the client desktop. I would appreciate any suggestions

Download method:

```
def download(request, pk):
  url = Model.objects.get(id=pk).__dict__["file1"]
  storage_client = storage.Client()
  bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(setting("GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME"))
  blob = storage.Blob(url, bucket)
  filename = url.rsplit("/", 1)[1]
  file_path = "temp/" + filename
  file_to_download = open(file_path, "rb")
  mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)
  response = HttpResponse(file_to_download, content_type=mime_type)
  response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
  return response
```

Response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 29 Oct 2021 08:01:15 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.9.7
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=default.jpg
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 10994
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
```

Request headers

```
GET /api/models/download/26/ HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A 
Brand";v="99"
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 
Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Mobile Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Android"
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938718/how-to-download-files-using-axios

Comment: Thank you, however, I need the response from the server to be the file, which is then downloaded to the client. I believe by using header "Content-Disposition" = "attachment" the file should be downloaded?

Comment: Are you testing your request with postman?

Comment: Yeah, I use postman to make the requests and the response returned is the image I need to be downloaded

Comment: In postman, there is a dropdown in the Send button where you can select Send and download instead. Make sure you are using this option

Comment: This works inside postman, how do I make this file download on client side?

Comment: Have you tried in client side? IIRC it should automatically work

Comment: Exactly the same request from vue, but no download. Tested on safari and chrome, same result

Comment: Could you please edit your post adding the headers you are using to send the request? Do not include sensitive information like tokens or similar stuff

Comment: sure, request headers added

Answer (score 1):

It's a sad day for axios and content-disposition https://medium.com/@drevets/you-cant-prompt-a-file-download-with-the-content-disposition-header-using-axios-xhr-sorry-56577aa706d6

The solution will be along the lines of the following code, from the front-end:

```
axios({
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/static/example.pdf',
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'blob', // important
}).then((response) => {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
});
```