# How do i fetch data with Axios that isn't json data

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch

How do i fetch data with Axios that isn't json data. such as data just from a website [the data i want to fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imahD.png)

Comment: kindly provide the data examples, I cant understand the image u have attached. What do u mean by data just from a website, explain clearly

Answer (score 0):

Use option `responseType`

Example download image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53230807/6250402

```
  // `responseType` indicates the type of data that the server will respond with
  // options are: 'arraybuffer', 'document', 'json', 'text', 'stream'
  //   browser only: 'blob'
  responseType: 'json', // default
```

Read more: https://github.com/axios/axios