# How do I send a variable from the server as a downloadable text file with a specific file name?

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I have a controller method in my inversify-express-utils app that looks something like this:

```
return await this.downloadReportUseCase.invoke(String(req.query.report_id), String(req.query.user_id))
            .then(async ([filename, filedata]: [string, string]) => {
                return res.status(200).sendFile(fs.writeFileSync(filename, filedata)); // I want to do something like this
            })
            .catch((err: Error) => {
                res.status(500).json(err);
            });
```

Note the comment, how do i achieve something like that? I don't actually want to create a file on the server, i just want a the variable to be sent to the end user in the form of a file that is either XML or CSV file type.

Answer (score 1):

With `fs.writeFileSync` you *do* actually create a file on the server. Instead, use

```js
res.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
res.end(filedata);
```

Comment: With this im getting the data through to the client but im not getting a file download, its just in the response. How do i get a file to download onto the client machine with this data in?

Comment: The `Content-Disposition` header causes (my) browser to download the file.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of this question: [How to download files using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938718/how-to-download-files-using-axios)

and using `res.attachment` in my controller allowed me to download the file