# How to download a file using axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am using Vue js to make a post request to a backend API. The response data should be downloaded into a zip file.
Though the file downloads as a zip file, I get an error when I try to open the file.
Error message: Windows cannot open the folder. The compressed (zipped) folder "........\test.zip" is invalid.

Here is my vue code

```
let config = {
    Headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      responseType: "blob",
    },
  };
  axios
    .post(
      `http://localhost:5050/generator`,
      this.forms,
      config
    )
    .then((response) => {
      const zipName = "test";
      this.forms = {
        productName: "",
        companyName: "",
      
      };
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/zip" })
      );
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute("download", zipName + ".zip"); 
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
    });
```

**Update**

I used this code

```
function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
          var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
          var len = binary_string.length;
          var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
          for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
          }
          return bytes.buffer;
        }
```

to convert it to a UintArray. I received another error 'DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.'

Comment: what is the value of `response.data` if its base64 you will need to convert it to a unit8  bit array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download files using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938718/how-to-download-files-using-axios)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen it returns a zip file. When I tried to convert it, I get another error `DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.`

Comment: @Blackmore you wil first need to remove the `base64, data/etc` instial string from the base64 encoding string

Comment: log your string to console first

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FileSaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver):

```js
import SaveAs from "file-saver";

.....
.then((response) => 
{
  ....
  saveAs(new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), response.filename, { autoBOM: false });
}
```