# Zipped folder is invalid when I try to download it through AXIOS get request

Tags: node.js, vue.js, postman

I have an app writen in NodeJs (backend) and VueJS (frontend). I am trying to download a zip file generated in the app on the frontend with the following code:

```
const downloadZIP = () => {

      AXIOS_REQUEST("GET", "/download", {

        responseType: "blob",

      })

        .then((response) => {

          const blob = new Blob([response.data], {

            type: "application/zip",

          });

          const link = document.createElement("a");

          link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

          link.setAttribute("download", "logs.zip");

          link.click();

          URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);

        })

        .catch((error) => {

          console.error(error);

        });

    };
```

The download is successful, but when I am trying to open the zip it gives me the error message "The compressed folder is invalid". On the other hand, the download through Postman (implemented with res.download) works perfect and the zip file can be opened successfully. What can be the problem? Maybe the type: "application/zip"? It looks like the zip proccess is corrupted. Thank you!

I tried to Google other zip types but the issue still persists. Also, the file-saver didn't help: [How to download a file using axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73413275/how-to-download-a-file-using-axios)

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
responseType: 'blob',
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same issue after trying it.