# Synchronous download in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios

Need to query downloading of file array

I have an array with URL's of files to dowload:

```
const arrUrl = [
   'http://server.domain/path/file1.jpg',
   'http://server.domain/path/file2.jpg',
   'http://server.domain/path/file3.jpg', 
];
```

when i try to download files with Axios and code:

```
arrUrl.forEach(async (element: string, i:number) => {
     const response = await new Axios({responseType: 'stream'}).get(element);
     await writeFile('./files/'+i, response.data);
     console.log(element);
});
```

All files start downloading at one time. But how can i download files in query mode? one-by-one

Comment: See these stackoverflow answers. It may help you.  [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938718/how-to-download-files-using-axios#:~:text=const%20FileDownload%20%3D%20require('js,csv')%3B%20%7D)

Comment: You can't use async in a `foreach` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using `async` function with `for-in (index)` of `for-of (element)` loop. Since we need to deal with loop `index` `for-in` is suitable here.

```js
const arrUrl = [
    'http://server.domain/path/file1.jpg',
    'http://server.domain/path/file2.jpg',
    'http://server.domain/path/file3.jpg',
];

async function downloadFiles(arrUrl) {
    for (let index in arrUrl) {
        const element = arrUrl[index];
        const response = await new Axios({ responseType: 'stream' }).get(element);
        await writeFile('./files/' + index, response.data);
    }
}

downloadFiles(arrUrl);
```