# How to use backend logic on Flask that generates files, on frontend

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, axios

I have a logic on backend (Flask) that generates csv files. When I access that endpoint through the browsers, it downloads the files automatically. When I access that endpoint from frontend (React) using Axios, I just get the response data, but it doesn't trigger the download automatically. What is the reason for this, and is there a way to do it without having to set Axios like here - [How to download files using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938718/how-to-download-files-using-axios)

Thanks

Comment: Probably the browser's behavior, but worth a second opinion.

Comment: simply use the link as the href path and a download attribute on an anchor link such as
`<a href="yourlinktothefile" download="filename.csv">Click to download</a>`