# Express res.download() don't work when calling from a function but work when direct call to API thorugh browser

Tags: javascript, express, axios

I've a button and when clicked it'll call the `downloadFile` function which make a call to backed to download a file.

```
async downloadFile(name) {
    await this.$axios.$get(process.env.API_LINK + '/api/files/' + name)
},
```

```
app.get('/api/files/:name', (req, res) => {
    res.download('files/' + req.params.name, function (error) {
      console.log('Error : ', error);
    });
})
```

When the button is clicked, the console print the error as `undefined` BUT when I direct access the API through the browser (`localhost:9000/api/files/teste.pdf`), the file is downloaded.

The file name is being correctly passed to the API when the button is clicked.

Edit (14.01.24, 19h36):

Changed the code according to [Express 4.x - API Reference](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html) (the `err` part) and added the `path.join()`. Now I don't get ANY error. Nothing happen. No file download and no error throw.

I can still download the file if I use the address `localhost:9000/api/files/teste.pdf` in the browser but if I make the call through a button (which call `downloadFile()` function) nothing happen.

```
.get('/files/:name', (req, res) => {
    res.download(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'files', req.params.name),  function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
     }
  });
})
```

Comment: Can you try to log `process.env.API_LINK + '/api/files/' + name`

Comment: When there is *no error*, the console log will output "undefined".  Your error function should check to see if `error` is defined before outputting it.  Look at the examples for res.download [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html) - the error function checks `if (err)` before outputting anything, otherwise it assumes everything succeeded.

Comment: Does that mean the file does not get downloaded in browser? if so what is the response? The only mistake I'm sensing here is that the express path should be /api/files/:name, tho not sure why it works on direct URL access

Comment: @kennarddh console.log output the following: `https://localhost:9000/api/files/teste.pdf`, if I take this output and paste in the browser it'll download the file.

Comment: I just want to make sure, are you trying to download a file on the front-end using `axios.get` without doing anything with the response?

Comment: @jQueeny Actually yes, that's what I'm doing. I thought that if it works if I do it using the `localhost:9000/api/files/teste.pdf` address direct in the browser, it would also work if I make the call through the front-end.

Comment: @HarryHsu Yes, if I type the `localhost:9000/api/files/teste.pdf` in the address the file is download. As @jQueeny pointed out, maybe there's something that I should to in the backend to send a response to front-end. I'll try to find it out.

Comment: In axios you need to handle the response as a `blob`. This is a common task. See [this question and it's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938718/how-to-download-files-using-axios)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using the [tutorial in this page](https://dev.to/webplayground/how-to-use-resdownload-to-download-images-3gk8).

I basically had to use:

```
downloadFile(name) {
    window.location.href = process.env.API_LINK + '/api/files/' + name
}
```

Instead of:

```
async downloadFile(name) {
    await this.$axios.$get(process.env.API_LINK + '/api/files/' + name)
},
```