# How to Retrieve a File from API Endpoint with Axios in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I'm trying to retrieve a file from a specific API endpoint using Axios in my ReactJS frontend application. The API endpoint is designed to provide a file (PDF) as a response when called with the appropriate parameters. Here's an example of the endpoint definition:

```
@GET
@Path("/acceptance-by-token/{recipient_token}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Operation(summary = "Retrieve the acceptance proof of a record")
@ApiResponse(
        responseCode = "200",
        description = "the pdf proof of the record acceptance",
        content = [Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)]
)
@ApiResponse(
        description = "Error in case that the acceptance proof is not available",
        content = [Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = Schema(implementation = RestErrorMessage::class))]
)
fun acceptanceProofByRecipientToen(
        @PathParam("recipient_token") recipientToken: String
)
    val acceptanceProof = proofService.getAcceptanceProofByRecipientToken(recipientToken)
    val filename = acceptanceProof.fileName
    httpServletResponse.status = HttpStatus.OK.value()
    httpServletResponse.contentType = acceptanceProof.mimeType
    httpServletResponse.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, """attachment; filename="$filename"""")
    acceptanceProof.inputStream.use { stream ->
        stream.transferTo(httpServletResponse.outputStream)
    }
    httpServletResponse.outputStream.flush()
}
```

My question is: How can I use Axios in ReactJS to properly call this API endpoint and retrieve the file as a downloadable attachment?

I have attempted to make a GET request to the endpoint using Axios, but I'm unsure of how to handle the file response and enable it to be downloaded by the user.

Any guidance or examples demonstrating how to achieve this using Axios in a ReactJS environment would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download files using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938718/how-to-download-files-using-axios)